# How can I draw a video on the html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Game</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <video id="video" src="./SpaceBG.mp4" style="display: none;"></video>
  
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

js:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
canvas.width = 720
canvas.height = 480

var video = document.getElementById('video');
```

So that is bassicly the code I'm working with in my Test-project.
How can I now draw a video on the canvas? I already saw some stakoverflows that kinda asked the same question but with a few extras I also can't find much about it on the internet.